# Creating a monotonic list with groupby with missing dates

Tags: pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, rolling-computation

I am finding the rolling average of all counties over a period of time. However, the first county, county "A", is missing the time point for January 3rd.

```
def crt_data():
    data = [[datetime(2020, 1, 1), 'A', 1],
         [datetime(2020,1,2), 'A', 2],
         #[datetime(2020,1,3), 'A', 3],
         [datetime(2020,1,4), 'A', 4],
         [datetime(2020,1,1), 'B', 10],
         [datetime(2020,1,2), 'B', 11],
         [datetime(2020,1,3), 'B', 12],
         [datetime(2020,1,4), 'B', 13],
         [datetime(2020,1,1), 'C', 4],
         [datetime(2020,1,2), 'C', 3],
         [datetime(2020,1,3), 'C', 2],
         [datetime(2020,1,4), 'C', 1]
           ]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['my_date', 'County', 'cmi'])
    return df

df = crt_data()

print('\n \n roll over  by timepoint')
df['my_mean'] = df.groupby('my_date')['cmi'].mean().reset_index(0, drop=True)
df = df.sort_values(by=['County', 'my_date'])
df['rolling_cmi2'] = df.my_mean.rolling(2).mean()
print(df)

      my_date County  cmi   my_mean  rolling_cmi2
0  2020-01-01      A    1  5.000000           NaN
1  2020-01-02      A    2  5.333333      5.166667
2  2020-01-04      A    4  7.000000      6.166667
3  2020-01-01      B   10  6.000000      6.500000
4  2020-01-02      B   11       NaN           NaN
5  2020-01-03      B   12       NaN           NaN
6  2020-01-04      B   13       NaN           NaN
7  2020-01-01      C    4       NaN           NaN
8  2020-01-02      C    3       NaN           NaN
9  2020-01-03      C    2       NaN           NaN
10 2020-01-04      C    1       NaN           NaN
```

EDIT:
What I expect to see is something like this:

```
     my_date County  cmi   my_mean  rolling_cmi2
0  2020-01-01      A    1  5.000000           NaN
1  2020-01-02      A    2  5.333333      5.166667
3  2020-01-03      B   12  7.000000      6.166667
2  2020-01-04      A    4  7.000000      7.000000
```

When I group, I get no dates for January third, and two dates for January 1st. This makes the rolling value incorrect.

How do I reduce it to a single average with one of each of the dates, and that date be the correct date? I know County C has all the correct time points, can I move County C to the top of the list to get a complete list of dates? How would you do this?

Comment: rolling_cmi2 must be a rolling avg of cmi by county?

Comment: I want rolling_cmi2 to be a rolling average of all the counties.